# I used both the Leibniz and the Wallis formulas for estimating π but am getting wrong output numbers, I couldn't figure out where did I go wrong

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath> \\not sure if I need cmath
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

this while loop serves to loop the " enter  number of terms to approximate.

```
while (a != 0)
{
```

here is the  Leibniz  formula:

```
double c = 0.00, d = 0.00;
            for (int i = 1; i <= a)
            {

                if (i % 2 != 0)
                {


                    d = 1 / (1 + 2 * (i - 1));
                }
                else
                {

                    d = -1 / (1 + 2 * (i - 1));

                }
                c = c + d;
                i = i + 1

            }
            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
            cout.precision(5);
            cout << "The approximation for Leibniz's Formula is " << c << " 
    using "<< a <<" terms." << endl;
```

here is the Wallis formula:

```
double e = 1.00;
            for (int u = 0; u<a; u++)
            {
                e = e * (2 * a / (2 * a - 1))*(2 * a / (2 * a + 1));

            }

            cout << "The approximation for Wallis' Formula is " << e << " using 
    "<< a <<" terms." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Enter the number of terms to approximate (or zero to 
    quit):" << endl;
            cin >> a;
        }
```

For a=1 I am getting 1.0000 in the first formula output and 0.00000 in the second formula output

Comment: Learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

A line like this

```
d = 1 / (1 + 2 * (i - 1));
```

will use integer arithmetics to calculate the result, and then convert the `int` result to a `double`.

Change it to

```
d = 1.0 / (1 + 2 * (i - 1));
```

or even

```
d = 1.0 / (1.0 + 2.0 * (i - 1.0));
```

Comment: I see, this indeed fixed the 0 and 1 output problem. however I could not find the logic error in my programming of these two formulas because I am still getting incorrect outputs. For a=5 the output should be 2.97605 and 3.00218 yet I am getting 6.89524 and 2.10307. Could you help me find the logical error as well please? thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes in this code. First, comments in c++ use `//`, not `\\`.

```
#include <cmath> //not sure if I need cmath
```

You have to have two semicolons in **for** statements, even if you don't need *loop-expression*.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a;)
```

The *d* will evaluate to 0 for every *i* that is greater than 1. You are using integer division, when you clearly want floating point division. You have to tell that to the compiler like this.

```
d = 1.0 / (1 + 2 * (i - 1));
```

When the left argument of division operator is *double* compiler will know, that you want to perform a floating point division. If it would be *int* as in your code, integer division would be performed and result converted to *double*.

Also in the Wallis formula you misplaced *a* for *u*, and also *u* parameter should start at 1, not 0. Also the integer division problem persists here.

```
double e = 1.00;
for (int u = 1; u<a; u++)
{
    e = e * (2.0 * u / (2.0 * u - 1))*(2.0 * u / (2.0 * u + 1));
}
```

If you fix this all, the program starts to output valid results.